# How to remove JSONArray element using Java

Tags: java, json, hibernate, extjs4

My JsonArray is

```
[{
"Id": null,
"Name": "One New task",
"StartDate": "2010-02-03T05:30:00",
"EndDate": "2010-02-04T05:30:00",
"Duration": 1,
"DurationUnit": "d",
"PercentDone": 0,
"ManuallyScheduled": false,
"Priority": 1,
"parentId": 8,
"index": 0,
"depth": 3,
"checked": null },{
"Id": null,
"Name": "New task",
"StartDate": "2010-02-04T05:30:00",
"EndDate": "2010-02-04T05:30:00",
"Duration": 0,
"DurationUnit": "d",
"PercentDone": 0,
"ManuallyScheduled": false,
"Priority": 1,
"parentId": 8,
"index": 1,
"depth": 3,
"checked": null }]
```

Now from this JsonArray I want to remove Id, ManuallyScheduled, checked,

I tried using `jsonArray.remove(1)` and also `jsonArray.discard("Id")` in JAVA.
but nothing happens. what am I doing wrong to remove array items?

I am using JAVA as my technology.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have there is an array of objects. Therefore you'll have to loop through the array and remove the necessary data from **each** object, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0, len = jsonArr.length(); i < len; i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    // Do your removals
    obj.remove("id");
    // etc.
}
```

I've assumed you're using `org.json.JSONObject` and `org.json.JSONArray` here, but the principal remains the same whatever JSON processing library you're using.

If you wanted to convert something like `[{"id":215},{"id":216}]` to `[215,216]` you could so something like:

```
JSONArray intArr = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0, len = objArr.length(); i < len; i++) {
    intArr.put(objArr.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear it :-) You could always extend `JSONArray` and add a `removeData(String... keys)` method or something similar if this was something you wanted to do regularly.

Comment: one more question to you.. How can i just pass the value to JSONArray in java. like I am having jsonArray of form **[{"id":215},{"id":216}]** but i want to convert my jsonArray to **[215,216]** is there any way to do so ?? how can i achieve this.

Comment: You could do this manually, I'll update my answer to show how to do this.

Comment: Hi I am having the same problem I am receiving the date in format of **2012-01-30T00:00:00** so how can I assign it to my Date variable startDate in JAVA pojo class.

Comment: I should think you'll have to use `.getString("date")` and then manually parse the `String` into a `Date` using something like `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: how to parse the date String i received from String to Date using SimpleDateFormate ?? Do you have any idea.. My String Date is **2012-01-30T00:00:00**

Comment: If you don't mind about the time (i.e. it's always `00:00:00`) then you could just remove that bit and then parse. e.g. `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-DD"); Date d = sdf.parse(str.split("T")[0]);` Here's the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc.

Comment: I tried to use your solution but don't know my sysout is not working I am not able to parse using **SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YY-MM-DD"); Date d = sdf.parse(jsonObject.getString("StartDate").split("T")[0]);** my java console is not giving any error and the line not executing

Comment: Try `yyyy-MM-dd` for the `SimpleDateFormat` pattern.

Answer (score 2):

This is useful sometimes in android when you want to use the json structure directly.

Notice that I only use this when I'm handling JSONObject inside the array.

```
public static JSONArray remove(final int idx, final JSONArray from) {
    final List<JSONObject> objs = asList(from);
    objs.remove(idx);

    final JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    for (final JSONObject obj : objs) {
        ja.put(obj);
    }

    return ja;
}

public static List<JSONObject> asList(final JSONArray ja) {
    final int len = ja.length();
    final ArrayList<JSONObject> result = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final JSONObject obj = ja.optJSONObject(i);
        if (obj != null) {
            result.add(obj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why add to a list<> and not directly add to a new JSONArray?

Comment: yes, you can do that. I have the unoptimized version because I already had the method asList for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

The following method will find the object in an `array` with the matching `id`, then return the filtered array.

```
public JSONArray removeObject(JSONArray array, String id) throws JSONException {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        if (obj.getString("ID").equals(id)) {
            array.remove(i);
            //  Toast.makeText(this, "ENCONTRADO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```