# How to make JSONArray empty or delete it

Tags: android, json

After completion of execution of an activity i want to make jSONArray empty or delete it. Because when i am calling the activity repeatedly the new data gets append to the old data present in JSONArray. My jsonArray is as shown below..

```
[{"record":[
            {......},
            {.......}
           ]
 },
 {"record":[
            {..........},
            {.........}
           ]
 }
] 


First time:
[{"record":[{"intensity":"Low","Body_SubParts":"Scalp","symptom":"Bleeding"}]}]

Second time:
[{"record":[{"intensity":"Low","Body_SubParts":"Scalp","symptom":"Bleeding"},
{"intensity":"Low","Body_SubParts":"Eyes","symptom":"Bleeding"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8740464/799188)

```
// Assuming you have constructed the replacement as
JSONObject jsonArray11_obj2 = new JSONObject();
jsonArray11_obj2.put("intensity", "high");
jsonArray11_obj2.put("Body_SubParts", "Scalp");
// ...

// Then the code doing the replacement would look similar to
int index = 0;
((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(index)).getJSONArray("record").put(0, jsonArray11_obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

After building the `JSON` array, nullify the `JSONArray` object..Next time again build the `JSON` Array