# JSONArray remove cannot find symbol error in JAVA

Tags: java, json, arrays

[Description]
1. Using Java
2. Use org.json.JSONArray and org.json.JSONObject
[Problem]
When I call JSONArray's `remove()` method, always get "cannot find symbol: method remove(int)" when compile my project, any help for this?

Here is a similar question: [How to remove JSONArray element using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740377/how-to-remove-jsonarray-element-using-java)
but the answer seems not correct, because that will just remove the inside JSONObject's key-value pair but not the whole insinde JSONObject.

Example code:

```
JSONArray test_arr = new JSONArray("[{'id':'1', 'name': 'name1'},{'id':'2', 'name':'name2'}]");
test_arr.remove(1);  // here will cause the "cannot find symbol" error.
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using (say) an old version of the lib that doesn't have that particular method ?

Comment: [Check this][1]
Its may Helpful to You... Remove json array using name-value


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310623/remove-item-from-json-array-using-its-name-value

Comment: [to Brian] I checked the jar file which I use, it do has remove method.
[to Pratik] Thanks, but I said I use java, not javascript.

Comment: Hmmm, the `remove(int)` method has been in the codebase since the [very first commit](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/commit/667813de3cbdcd0d39459499ad283fd03937d89d). This has to be an error in how you included the code into your project.

Comment: [to Perception] I use java, so ==> include "org.json.jar" in library path, and "import org.json.JSONArray;" in code.
Other functions of this class works well in my project, but only this remove() function.

Comment: Make sure that the function exists in your jar, you can use this [tool](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) or any other

Comment: [to NightWhisper] Yes, I already checked, it do have.

Comment: Mentioning that you were using a JAR was quite useful, see my answer below. Also, to notify a SO user, put an @ in front of their name (instead of typing [to Whoever]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, interestingly, the latest org.json JAR in Maven central indeed contains a `JSONArray` class that **does not** have a remove method. This is an extract of javap on the class, as extracted from json-20090211.jar:

```
public org.json.JSONArray put(int, long) throws org.json.JSONException;
public org.json.JSONArray put(int, java.util.Map) throws org.json.JSONException;
public org.json.JSONArray put(int, java.lang.Object) throws org.json.JSONException;
public org.json.JSONObject toJSONObject(org.json.JSONArray) throws org.json.JSONException;
public java.lang.String toString();
public java.lang.String toString(int) throws org.json.JSONException;
java.lang.String toString(int, int) throws org.json.JSONException;
public java.io.Writer write(java.io.Writer) throws org.json.JSONException;
```

This compiled code is inconsistent with the [source code](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/) available from the [official JSON.org site](http://www.json.org/java/index.html), so I would ***not*** use it. The library is so dead simple, I would recommend simply grabbing the source yourself and either:

- compiling it into a JAR
- including it directly into your project.

Comment: Thanks Perception.
In my project, i decompile the org.json.jar, it DO has a remove() method. Have no idea about why got this "cannot find symbol" error.

Now I use ArrayList<JSONObject> instead of JSONArray, then I can use ArrayList's remove() method.

Thanks again for your help and advice.